# How to set a minimum order price within this code

Tags: php, cart, checkout

Looking at a piece of code at the moment and trying to work out how to set a minimum order price of £10 within this code. I want the 'Confirm your order' CTA to be inactive unless the order is £10 - Or maybe upon selecting the CTA, no action, just a message to display saying the order should be £10 or over when the CTA is selected.

Any help would be great, I have a huge headache from this. I've been trying to learn to code but I am in way over my head with this one.

```
    <?php
use mp_restaurant_menu\classes\models;
use mp_restaurant_menu\classes\View;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
function mprm_is_checkout() {
    return models\Checkout::get_instance()->is_checkout();
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
function mprm_get_checkout_uri() {
    return models\Checkout::get_instance()->get_checkout_uri();
}

function mprm_get_checkout_cart_template() {
    $data = array();
    $data[ 'is_ajax_disabled' ] = models\Settings::get_instance()->is_ajax_disabled();
    $data[ 'cart_items' ] = models\Cart::get_instance()->get_cart_contents();
    mprm_get_template('shop/checkout-cart', $data);
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
function mprm_checkout_button_next() {
    $color = mprm_get_option('checkout_color', 'mprm-btn blue');
    $color = ($color == 'inherit') ? '' : $color;
    $padding = mprm_get_option('checkout_padding', 'mprm-inherit');
    $style = mprm_get_option('button_style', 'button');
    $purchase_page = mprm_get_option('purchase_page', '0');
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="mprm_action" value="gateway_select"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="<?php echo absint($purchase_page); ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="gateway_submit" id="mprm_next_button" class="mprm-submit <?php echo $color; ?> <?php echo $padding; ?> <?php echo $style; ?>" value="<?php _e('Next', 'mp-restaurant-menu'); ?>"/>
    <?php
    return apply_filters('mprm_checkout_button_next', ob_get_clean());
}

/**
 * Checkout purchase button
 * @return mixed
 */
function mprm_checkout_button_purchase() {
    $color = mprm_get_option('checkout_color', 'mprm-btn blue');
    $color = ($color == 'inherit') ? '' : $color;
    $style = mprm_get_option('button_style', 'button');
    $label = mprm_get_option('checkout_label', '');
    $padding = mprm_get_option('checkout_padding', 'mprm-inherit');
    if (mprm_get_cart_total()) {
        $complete_purchase = !empty($label) ? $label : __('Purchase', 'mp-restaurant-menu');
    } else {
        $complete_purchase = !empty($label) ? $label : __('Free Menu item', 'mp-restaurant-menu');
    }
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <input type="submit" class="mprm-submit <?php echo $color; ?> <?php echo $padding; ?> <?php echo $style; ?>" id="mprm-purchase-button" name="mprm-purchase" value="<?php echo $complete_purchase; ?>"/>
    <?php
    return apply_filters('mprm_checkout_button_purchase', ob_get_clean());
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
function mprm_is_no_guest_checkout() {
    return models\Misc::get_instance()->no_guest_checkout();
}

function mprm_checkout_tax_fields() {
    if (models\Taxes::get_instance()->cart_needs_tax_address_fields() && mprm_get_cart_total()) {
        mprm_default_cc_address_fields();
    }
}

function mprm_checkout_submit() { ?>
    <fieldset id="mprm_purchase_submit">
        <?php do_action('mprm_purchase_form_before_submit'); ?>
        <?php mprm_checkout_hidden_fields(); ?>
        <?php echo mprm_checkout_button_purchase(); ?>
        <?php do_action('mprm_purchase_form_after_submit'); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}

function mprm_checkout_additional_information() {
    View::get_instance()->get_template('/shop/checkout-additional-information');
}

function mprm_checkout_final_total() {
    ?>
    <p id="mprm_final_total_wrap">
        <strong><?php _e('Total:', 'mp-restaurant-menu'); ?></strong>
        <span class="mprm_cart_amount" data-subtotal="<?php echo mprm_get_cart_subtotal(); ?>" data-total="<?php echo mprm_get_cart_subtotal(); ?>"><?php echo mprm_currency_filter(mprm_format_amount(mprm_get_cart_total())); ?></span>
    </p>
    <?php
}

function mprm_checkout_hidden_fields() {
    ?>
    <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="mprm-user-id" value="<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>"/>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="mprm_action" value="purchase"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="controller" value="cart"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mprm-gateway" value="<?php echo models\Gateways::get_instance()->get_chosen_gateway(); ?>"/>
    <?php
}

/**
 *  Delivery address default
 */
function mprm_checkout_delivery_address() {
    if (mprm_get_option('shipping_address')): ?>
        <p id="mprm-address-wrap">
            <label for="shipping_address" class="mprm-label">
                <?php _e('Shipping address:', 'mp-restaurant-menu'); ?>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="shipping_address" value="" class="medium-text" placeholder="<?php _e('Enter your address.', 'mp-restaurant-menu'); ?>"/>
        </p>
    <?php endif;
}

/**
 * Checkout order notes
 */
function mprm_checkout_order_note() {
    ?>
    <p id="mprm-phone-number-wrap">
        <label for="customer_note" class="mprm-label">
            <?php _e('Order notes:', 'mp-restaurant-menu'); ?>
        </label>
        <textarea type="text" name="customer_note" id="customer_note" class="phone-number mprm-input"></textarea>
    </p>
<?php }

/**
 * Summary table
 */

function mprm_checkout_summary_table() { ?>

    <span class="mprm-payment-details-label"><legend><?php _e('Order totals', 'mp-restaurant-menu'); ?></legend></span>
    <table class="mprm-table">
        <?php do_action('mprm_checkout_table_subtotal_before'); ?>
        <tr>
            <td class=""><span><?php _e('Subtotal', 'mp-restaurant-menu'); ?> </span></td>
            <td><span class="mprm_cart_subtotal_amount"><?php echo mprm_currency_filter(mprm_format_amount(mprm_get_cart_subtotal())) ?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <?php do_action('mprm_checkout_table_subtotal_after'); ?>

        <?php do_action('mprm_checkout_table_tax_before'); ?>
        <?php if (mprm_use_taxes()) : ?>
            <tr <?php if (!mprm_is_cart_taxed()) echo ' style="display:none;"'; ?>>
                <td><span><?php _e('Tax', 'mp-restaurant-menu'); ?></span></td>
                <td><span class="mprm_cart_tax_amount" data-tax="<?php echo mprm_get_cart_tax(); ?>"><?php echo mprm_currency_filter(mprm_format_amount(mprm_get_cart_tax())) ?></span></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php do_action('mprm_checkout_table_tax_after'); ?>

        <?php do_action('mprm_checkout_table_total_before'); ?>
        <tr class="mprm-checkout-total">
            <td>
                <span><b><?php _e('Total', 'mp-restaurant-menu'); ?></b></span>
            </td>
            <td><span class="mprm_cart_amount"><b><?php echo mprm_currency_filter(mprm_format_amount(mprm_get_cart_total())) ?></b></span></td>
        </tr>
        <?php do_action('mprm_checkout_table_total_after'); ?>
    </table>

<?php }

/**
 * Send to success page
 *
 * @param string $query_string
 */
function mprm_send_to_success_page($query_string) {
    return models\Checkout::get_instance()->send_to_success_page($query_string);
}

/**
 * Send back to checkout
 *
 * @param $args
 */
function mprm_send_back_to_checkout($args) {
    return models\Checkout::get_instance()->send_back_to_checkout($args);
}
```

Comment: Just asking: are you _really_ sure it is a good idea to operate an online business (which means you FULLY have to rely and submit to the business that code performs) if you apparently have no clue how that code works?

Comment: I'm not operating a business, I am trying to learn php for my course